react-native-qrcode-scanner at Empty QR code
I am developing react native app, there is a QR code scanner screen, i want to trigger an alert if the QR code which i try to scan is empty. QR code with data work fine.
i am using version :
"react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.3",
please help me.
I tried to add a logic through onread event  to check the data null or empty,it did not work,  But when i scanned empty QR code it continuously scanning, does not go through handleBarCodeScanned function.
 const handleBarCodeScanned = ({data}: BarCodeReadEvent) => {
    console.log('Scanned QR code data1:', data);

    if (data !== null && data.trim() !== '') {
      const splitted = data.split('|')[0];
      dispatch(changeState(['isQRProcessing', true]));
      dispatch(scanQR({bookingRef: splitted.trim()}));
  } else {
    console.log('Empty QR Code or Timeout occurred');
      dispatch (
          showAlertModal(
              getAlertObject(
                  'Empty QR Code',
                  'Please scan a valid QR code.',
                  ALERT_TYPES.FAILED,
                  'Try Another',
                  'Close',
                  () => {
                      dispatch(changeState(['isQRProcessing', false]));
                  },
              ),
          )
      );
  }
};


{!isQRProcessing && (
          <QRCodeScanner
            onRead={handleBarCodeScanned}
            reactivate={true}
            reactivateTimeout={2000}
            showMarker={true}
            checkAndroid6Permissions={true}
            markerStyle={ScannerStyles.marker}
            cameraStyle={ScannerStyles.camera}
            cameraProps={{
              autoFocus: 'on',
            }}
          />
        )} 


The QR code needs some data to create the pattern to make it scannable. If a QR code doesn't have a pattern, it does not have some content. Then you don't need to check if a QR code is blank. You can read about it in this article, Blank QR Code: Can You Possibly Make One?
